# MVC ASP.NET -Ошибка HTTP Error 404.7 и отсутствующий файл applicationHost.configі

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Всем привет, возникла данная ошибка - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Microsoft  рекомендует исправлять это следующим образом
[Решение от Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/942045/error-message-when-you-try-to-browse-a-web-page-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7.0-http-error-404.7-file-extension-denied)

, но проблема в том , что по пути указанном в статье

> %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.configі

У меня нет ни папки \config , ни самого файла applicationHost.configі - в который они предлагают вносить спасительные изменения для решения проблемы.

Что делать?

---

Сдвинулся с мертвой точки - 
помогло следующее:

```
  <security>
<requestFiltering>
   <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
    <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
   <remove fileExtension=".cs" />
  </fileExtensions>
</requestFiltering>
```

- Т.е "тупо" выставил фильтры для расширения файлов - удалив их с помощью `remove`  и выставил  `allowUnlisted="true"` - пресловутые инструкции от Microsoft, указанные мною выше - не помогают, а только мешают. Теперь выдает ошибку

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и должно быть - вы в браузере указали путь к исходникам, http://localhost:49525/Home/UsersController.cs.

Скорее всего у вас этот файл задан как "стартовый" в настройках проекта - случайно нажали на нем set as startup page в solution explorer.

Настройки безопасности не дают вам вытянуть исходники как текст, а вы в ответ пытаетесь их поломать. Просто удалите из адресной строки  UsersController.cs - и ваше приложение откроется.

Не забудьте откатить изменения в настройках фильтрации на стандартные и подправить настройки проекта, чтобы студия не открывала неправильный URL при запуске.

Comment: Как подправить настройки фильтрации?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Регистрация", "UsersController.cs", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            @{
                var thing = @Scripts.Render("F:/Visual Studio Projects/WebForum/WebForum/Controllers/UsersController.cs/ViewPartial");

            }<br>

Comment: Я сам контроллеру указываю в ActionLink ссылке

Comment: @badcats ASP.NET MVC - не PHP. В MVC есть система роутинга. Вам нужно указывать ссылку на роут, а не вызывать все методы наугад. Ваш код пытается отрендерить содержимое cs-файла внутри тэга ссылки. Возьмите стандартный шаблонный проект и посмотрите как там сделаны ссылки на регистрацию.